# client app (steroids, ionic, cordova) using Breeze cannot connect to WebApi OData for metadata. Invalid HTTP status code 405

Tags: metadata, odata, breeze

I create a WebApi 2.2 OData v1-3 which uses Code First. Here is my ODataConfig

```
public static class ODataConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        #region Normal way to build EDM model the Microsoft way
        ODataModelBuilder builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
        builder.EntitySet<Gear>("Gears");
        ...
        #endregion

        // enable CORS
        var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "*", "DataServiceVersion, MaxDataServiceVersion");
        config.EnableCors(cors);

        config.Routes.MapODataServiceRoute(
            routeName: "odata",
            routePrefix: "odata",
            model: builder.GetEdmModel());
    }
}
```

In my Global.asax.cs I call it in the Application_Start()

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configure(ODataConfig.Register);
```

My controller is a ODataController

```
public class GearsController : ODataController
{...}
```

I can build the project and try those with no problem

```
localhost:51131/OData/Gears
```

> {
>     "odata.metadata":"http://localhost:51131/odata/$metadata#Gears","value":[
>       {
>         "Title":"Burton 729","Description":"Burton 720","Size":"12","Defects":"No defects","PricePerDay":12.0,"PricePerWeek":50.0,"AuthorizedAmount":400.0,"LikeCount":1,"ViewCount":25,"BootSize":10,"Banner":null,"OwnerID":3,"ID":3
>       },{
>         "Title":"Burton 360","Description":"Burton 360","Size":"10","Defects":"No defects","PricePerDay":12.0,"PricePerWeek":60.0,"AuthorizedAmount":450.0,"LikeCount":1,"ViewCount":25,"BootSize":11,"Banner":null,"OwnerID":1,"ID":4
>       }
>     ]
>   }

```
localhost:51131/OData/$metadata
```

Then I have a client which bower install the "angular", "breezejs", "datajs". I create a breezeODataService

```
(function () {
'use strict';

angular.module('tahoeApp.services.data').factory('breezeODataService', breezeODataService);
breezeODataService.inject = ['breeze', 'model'];
function breezeODataService(breeze, model) {
    configureBreeze();

    var serviceName = 'http://localhost:51131/odata';

    var metadataStore = new breeze.MetadataStore();
    var factory = {
        newManager: newManager,
        serviceName: serviceName,
        metadataStore: metadataStore
    };

    return factory;

    function configureBreeze() {
        // use Web API OData to query and save
        breeze.config.initializeAdapterInstance('dataService', 'webApiOData', true);

        // convert between server-side PascalCase and client-side camelCase
        breeze.NamingConvention.camelCase.setAsDefault();
    }

    function newManager() {
        var mgr = new breeze.EntityManager(serviceName);
        return mgr;
    }
}})();
```

Then I try to get all the Gear data from GearsController like this

```
function getAll() {
        var self = this;
        debugger;
        return EntityQuery.from('Gears')
            .using(self.manager).execute()
            .then(querySucceeded).catch(queryFailed);

        function querySucceeded(data) {
            debugger;
            return data.results;
        }

        function queryFailed(error) {
            throw error;
        }
    }
```

But it always returns to the

> queryFailed

with the message:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load [http:]localhost:51131/odata/$metadata. Invalid HTTP status code 405
>   ionic.bundle.js:17822 Error: Metadata query failed for: [http]localhost:51131/odata/$metadata; 
>       at createError (breeze.debug.js:16436)
>       at breeze.debug.js:16214
>       at XMLHttpRequest.r.defaultHttpClient.request.f.onreadystatechange (datajs-1.1.2.min.js:13)

Comment: Fyi, I also tried to seperate the **app** folder from ODataBreezejsSample project at [link](https://github.com/Breeze/breeze.js.samples/tree/master/net/ODataBreezejsSample) and edit the **entityManagerFactory.emFactory.serviceName** to _'http://localhost:55802/odata'_ and I encounter the same problem 'Metadata query failed for: http://localhost:55802/odata/$metadata;'. I can navigate to the $metadata though.

Comment: I have to download the Breeze.WebApi2 nuget package and re-config my OData Server using the BreezeWebApiConfig. Now my controller becomes a central for all my entities which looks like
'[Breeze.WebApi2.BreezeController]
    public class BreezeController : ODataController
    { }'
With it, my client app can connect to the server. I'm confused why it works with this method and cannot with an original ODataController?